# Make Highchart Map Tooltip Show Other Columns From Dataframe

Tags: r, tooltip, r-highcharter

I am creating a flex dashboard in R which includes a map of counties in Michigan using highchart. The input dataframe looks like this:

| County | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alcona | 15 | 8 | 26 |
| Alger | 10 | 11 | 13 |

I've created the map using Column B as the values. Currently the tooltip shows the name of the county, the numerical value in Column B, and a suffix of "%". What I want to do is continue making the map with the values from Column B, but make the tool tip show the values from Column C and Column D on different lines below as well. So I want the tooltip to look like this:

`[County Name]`

`Column B: [value]%`

`Column C [value]%`

`Column D: [value]%`

The code I used to create the map with the current tooltip is

`hcmap(  "countries/us/us-mi-all", data = df,  value = "Column B", joinBy = c("name", "County"), name = "Michigan Counties",      dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = "{point.name}"),      borderColor = "#FAFAFA",      borderWidth = 0.1, tooltip = list(     valueSuffix = "%"))`

I tried using the `tooltip.formatter` argument in Highcharts but I am new to the package so couldn't figure out how to make it work. Thank you in advance for your help!